# Takes lots of time when use aggregate function in the query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, query-performance

Table has 100 000 records, takes 20-21 seconds when use aggregate function. How to optimize this query?

```
SELECT source, sum(product_price*quantity) AS price 
FROM `sheet` 
WHERE source !='' 
GROUP BY source 
ORDER BY `price` DESC
```

I have also used indexing in the table

```
ALTER TABLE `dbname`.`sheet` ADD INDEX `reprting_module` (`source`(30));
```

This is the output after explain the query

[image]

Comment: Give us the table definitions including the indexes

Comment: apply indexing ..

Comment: Have you index on source?

Comment: Do the fact your grouping  all but not source ='' , you could manage this row server side ..

Comment: How to manage in the server side.I am not getting you @ scaisEdge

Comment: Table has **InnoDB engine**. and **source column** is text type.

Comment: Whatever "1 lakh record" is, run [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) to look for missing indices

Comment: The terms *lakh* and *crore* are specific to India. For a worldwide audience, it's helpful to translate them. 1 lakh = 100k. 1 crore = 10m.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're asking your MySQL server to do some computation in this query, and then to sort the results. It will take some time. It necessarily must examine every, or almost every, row of your table. There's no magic to make those operations instantaneous.

Secondly, your `WHERE source != ''` filter may be defeating your indexing. You could try `WHERE source > ''` instead. That will allow MySQL's query planner to random-access your index, then scan it sequentially.

Third, your subset `source` index (`source(30)`) doesn't help performance.

Fourth, you can try creating a compound covering index on these columns:

```
    ALTER TABLE dbname.sheet 
      ADD INDEX `reprting_module` (source, product_price, quantity);
```

Then write your query like this:

```
SELECT source, SUM(product_price*quantity) AS price 
  FROM sheet 
 WHERE source > '' 
 GROUP BY source 
 ORDER BY SUM(product_price*quantity) DESC
```

If you're lucky this will be a little faster. Why? Because MySQL can satisfy your entire query by random-accessing the index to the first non-empty `source` value, then sequentially scanning just the index to perform your computation.

Notice that the query I showed, with the index I showed, will be very fast indeed if you use

```
     WHERE source = 'some-particular-value'
```

to narrow down the scope of the computation.

Answer (score 0):

"Prefix" indexes, such as `INDEX(source(30))`, are virtually useless.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  If `source` could be `VARCHAR(255)` or smaller, simply add `INDEX(source)`  But that is probably not useful here, since most of the table needs to be read.

How much RAM do you have?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How big (GB) is the table?  These combine to ask whether you are CPU-bound or I/O-bound, and whether a simple tuning fix can change it from I/O to CPU, thereby possibly speeding it up to 2 seconds.  (20 seconds seems very high for a mere 100K rows.)

Comment: In my case **source type is text**

Comment: @Sumit - but does it _need_ to be?  What is `MAX(LENGTH(source))`?  `TEXT` is not handled as efficiently as short `VARCHARs`.

Comment: Yep..now my problem is solved.Just changed the data Type of **source column** from text to varchar and apply appropriate indexing.Now it takes less than miliseconds.